# docker build returns "unexpected end of JSON input" on WSL2

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

When I try to build a docker image from WSL2 using

```bash
docker build .
```

it returns "unexpected end of JSON input".
Yet, when I try to build the image from PowerShell on Windows, it builds the image without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

After updating Docker Desktop, the issue was solved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).